# spring 4.1 javaConfg setting to get requestCache working

Tags: spring, spring-security

similar to this:
[Spring 3.1: Redirect after login not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19580071/spring-3-1-redirect-after-login-not-working)

when an authenticated user becomes inauthenticated while deep-linking into a single page web app.

Spring security redirects to logon but:
SavedRequest savedRequest = new HttpSessionRequestCache().getRequest(request, response);
is null

thus i cannot devine the url or params to send re-authenticated user to requested page

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .csrf().disable()

        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers() //redacted                .
            .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
            .and()

        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/x/y/logon")
            .usernameParameter("userLogon") //redacted 
            .loginProcessingUrl("/x/y/logon") //redacted 
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/x/", true)
            .failureUrl("/x/y/logon?error=true")
            .and()

        .logout()
            .logoutUrl("/x/y/logout")
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/x/")
            .permitAll();

}

}
```

-- controller --

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="/y/logon")
public ModelAndView logonHandler(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    List<Client> clients = //manager call for list of clients to show at logon        
    SavedRequest savedRequest = new HttpSessionRequestCache().getRequest(request, response);
    if (savedRequest != null) {
        String reqUrl = savedRequest.getRedirectUrl();
        String[] urlParams = reqUrl.split("&");
        String prefix = "";
        String urlParam = "";
        String cid = "";
        try {
            urlParam = urlParams[1];
        } catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException ioob) { }
        if (reqUrl.contains("cid=")) { cid = reqUrl.substring(reqUrl.indexOf("cid=")+4, reqUrl.indexOf("&")); }
        if (reqUrl.contains("?")) { reqUrl = reqUrl.substring(0, reqUrl.indexOf("?")); }
        prefix = reqUrl.substring(reqUrl.indexOf("/x/")+6, reqUrl.indexOf("/x/")+8);
        reqUrl = reqUrl.substring(reqUrl.indexOf(prefix)+2);
        if (reqUrl.contains("/")) {
            reqUrl = reqUrl.substring(0, reqUrl.indexOf("/"));
        }
        request.setAttribute("requestUrl", prefix+reqUrl);
        request.setAttribute("urlParam", urlParam);
        request.setAttribute("cid", cid);
    }
    request.setAttribute("IPAddress", request.getRemoteAddr());
    return new ModelAndView("x/logon", "clients", clients);
}
```

problem is, SavedRequest is null

is this an issue with:

alwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl property?

if yes, how in javaConfig does one set this property?

----- on edit to address comments ------

i'll explain my understanding of ea. .formLogon() settings: 
logonPage() will be read by spring and control redirect to logon page when you are not authorized (cookie expire/db record del, etc). There are many ways that a session can not be authorized and spring needs to know what page to send unauth requests to. My manual logon handler only handles requests to the logon url. 
usernameParameter() is to change from the default form input name thus obfuscating that one is using spring security. 
loginProcessingUrl() this seems to conflict with the custom logonHandler, but i think its req to handle the post and allow for spring to create a secure sesson.
 
defaultSucessUrl() tells spring where to go after successful logon (the post request). 
failureUrl() defines the url for failed logon.   
nowhere in my custom logon handler for the get request, are those settings in conflict... i think... but i've read the docs and the Spring Security 3 book and lots of online resources and i still do not feel as though i have a solid understanding of spring security... so i may be way off

Comment: Most of your `loginForm` settings are useless. Why because you are messing around with a controller  yourself and you don't let Spring handle it.  That already takes care of then behavior you want. Also if you would let Spring Security handle it it wouldn't work either because you told it to always redirect to the default URL basically disabling any redirect to the requested URL.

Comment: i'll explain my understanding of ea. .formLogon() settings:

Comment: And that understanding is wrong, nothing is being processed because that is directly passed on to your controller, effectively bypassing Spring Security.

Comment: SO basically you are destroying things yourself. Remove the `true` from `defaultSuccesUrl` as that will now always give you the default. If you remove it spring security will redirect you to the initially requested URL with the parameters.

Comment: one of first things i tried was remove "true" from defaultSuccessUrl(). SavedRequest still comes back null. Removing defaultSuccessUrl() competely forwards to the root app context without the <artifactId> defined in pom and thus gets 404. This used to work before migrating to javaConfig which is why i was looking for a javaConfig equivalent of alwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl. I really appreciate your feedback M. Deinum... my test was: logon, expire cookie and deep link (single page app).. the SavedRequest then used to extract url params and sent to hidden fields at login, then next logon links deep

Comment: The problem is you shouldn't have the controller, that is the culprit... You are messing around with behavior that Spring Security already does.